# How to copy a Subversion repository to another repository

Tags: svn, svnserve

We are running an SVN repository with svnserve. We have now created a new svnserve SVN repository on another machine in another network. I would now want to copy the active repository to the new repository. How can I do this? I would like to copy the repository, not move it.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by 'copy' -- do you mean you want a replication server, or do you want to back it up?

Comment: I want to move repository from machine A to machine B, by copying (not cutting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the repository folder to the other machine or use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication.svnsync) to replicate the repository over network.